# Jenkins- flutter : command not found in linux

Tags: flutter, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I have some doubts about CI-CD for Flutter Project. I tried to build flutter apk in Linux (ubuntu) using Jenkins I got an error flutter not found while using flutter comments in Jenkins. I set the global environmental variables for flutter and Android SDK it's possible to do flutter CI-CD in Jenkins on Linux environment
I run the project locally and build the application it's working fine
But I tried the same comments via Jenkins it's showing flutter not found
Does anyone knows this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U89H3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gryu.png)